# Тип Int в при списковых включениях Python

Tags: python, массивы, список

Всем привет!
Прохожу задания на pythontutor. Возник такой вопрос по двумерным массивам (вот, например задача - https://pythontutor.ru/lessons/2d_arrays/problems/chessboard/).
На вход подается 2 числа, чтобы затем сделать двумерный массив.
Подсмотрел, что числа подаются на вход вот так:

```
n,m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

После прочтения Луца я был уверен, что на выходе будет список - это же списковое включение.
Но оказалось, что на выходе 2 числа типа Int. Это как так?

```
n,m = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(n,m)
# 4 5
print(type(n), type(m))
# <class 'int'> <class 'int'>
```

Почему, когда мы присваиваем значения сразу 2-мя переменным, то на выходе оказывается формат Int? А если одной, то это получается список:

```
n = [int(i) for i in range(2)]
print(n)
# [0, 1]
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/

Comment: Вкратце - список (или любой итерируемый объект) из двух элементов справа от "равно" распаковывается на две отдельные переменные слева от "равно". Т.е. например `n, m = [1, 2]` (или `n, m = 1, 2`) по сути то же самое что `n = 1` и `m = 2` в отдельных строках.

Comment: А что на русском нет про это?

Comment: допустим, на выходе был бы список. А где бы он был? В m? В n?

Comment: для понимания попробуйте еще такую штуку `n,m,*t = range(5)` или `n,m = range(2)`

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/